# Difference between sequential/simultaneous nonlinear partial least squares and NIPALS algorithm

Tags: nonlinear, partial-least-squares

I've been reading about nonlinear partial least squares, and according to the below study, there are two types of NLPLS: sequential NLPLS and simultaenous NLPLS.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098135496003110

I'm a little confused by whether or not the NIPALS algorithm was developed based on either of these.